# I need some help understanding the jstack thread log

Tags: multithreading, thread-dump, jstack

There is an application that invokes JRE 1.7.0_80 to perform an "Add screenshot" process. That is the only process where JRE is being used.

The support team of that application discovered that this feature works good for some time, but after doing this 10 times or so it just hangs and nothing happens.

They got the below thread from the hung jp2launcher.exe process and I would like to get some help interpreting it.

```
2017-03-17 07:00:15
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode):

"Thread-15" #51 daemon prio=4 os_prio=-1 tid=0x065b2000 nid=0xf10 waiting on condition [0x195ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAnimationPanel2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"TimerQueue" #47 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x065b2400 nid=0x1700 waiting on condition [0x0880f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0e3fdad0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x0e4136a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

"ConsoleTraceListener" #44 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x065b1800 nid=0x20bc in Object.wait() [0x1947f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e0caa70> (a com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$BoundedStringBuffer)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$ConsoleWriterThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e0caa70> (a com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.ui.ConsoleTraceListener$BoundedStringBuffer)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-EventQueue-1" #35 prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x065b0400 nid=0x1f30 waiting on condition [0x081bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0e1d37a8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-EventQueue-2" #34 prio=4 os_prio=-1 tid=0x065b1400 nid=0x1578 waiting on condition [0x0847f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0e1ba298> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"JVM[id=17]-Heartbeat" #33 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x065b0c00 nid=0x204c in Object.wait() [0x082df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1ba4b8> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1ba4b8> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter$1.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter.runAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.server.HeartbeatThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Applet 9 LiveConnect Worker Thread" #31 prio=4 os_prio=-1 tid=0x065b0000 nid=0x23cc in Object.wait() [0x07e8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1ba698> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1ba698> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Browser Side Object Cleanup Thread" #29 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x065af800 nid=0x1b00 in Object.wait() [0x07adf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1ba830> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1ba830> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$BrowserSideObjectCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"CacheCleanUpThread" #28 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x065af400 nid=0x52c in Object.wait() [0x079af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1ba850> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1ba850> (a com.sun.deploy.cache.CleanupThread)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"CacheMemoryCleanUpThread" #25 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x065aec00 nid=0x1a04 in Object.wait() [0x0788f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1bab70> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1bab70> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$LoadedResourceCleanupThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"MemoryCache-DelayedCleanup" #26 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x065ae000 nid=0x23e4 in Object.wait() [0x0771f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1bad10> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1bad10> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"SysExecutionTheadCreator" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x065ad800 nid=0x1a70 in Object.wait() [0x075af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1bad20> (a sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1bad20> (a sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$SysExecutionThreadCreator)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-EventQueue-0" #20 prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x065a1800 nid=0x19cc waiting on condition [0x0723f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0e1bb028> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Windows" #18 daemon prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x0659d400 nid=0x1dd0 runnable [0x029ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Shutdown" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0659c800 nid=0x2054 in Object.wait() [0x0738f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1bb3c0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1bb3c0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Java2D Disposer" #16 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0659c000 nid=0x978 in Object.wait() [0x06a7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1bb560> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1bb560> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Java Plug-In Pipe Worker Thread (Client-Side)" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x065a8000 nid=0x19c0 runnable [0x06fef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.plugin2.os.windows.Windows.ReadFile0(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.os.windows.Windows.ReadFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.ipc.windows.WindowsNamedPipe.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.transport.NamedPipeTransport$SerializerImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.transport.NamedPipeTransport$SerializerImpl.readByte(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.AbstractSerializer.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.transport.SerializingTransport.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"MemoryPressure-Watchdog" #11 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x1904b800 nid=0x1b58 in Object.wait() [0x062ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e0722c0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e0722c0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"traceMsgQueueThread" #8 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x18eeac00 nid=0x1ea4 in Object.wait() [0x0605f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e0d7d50> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.trace.Trace$TraceMsgQueueChecker.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e0d7d50> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x18ed4800 nid=0x1bc0 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x18eab800 nid=0x2260 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x18eaa800 nid=0x1408 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x18eb1400 nid=0x176c runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x18e9dc00 nid=0x1680 in Object.wait() [0x0564f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e072d98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e072d98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x18e97c00 nid=0x1934 in Object.wait() [0x054df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e072f38> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e072f38> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0041ec00 nid=0x9f4 in Object.wait() [0x02e9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0e1bb800> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0e1bb800> (a sun.plugin2.message.Queue)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter$1.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter.runAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.main(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x18e72800 nid=0x1d1c runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x18ee2800 nid=0x19ac waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 569
```

Comment: Main, Finalizer, Reference Handler, CacheMemoryCleanUpThread, and Browser Side Object Cleanup threads are waiting on a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock. 3 AWT queue threads are waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject

Comment: Thank you!! I think this will be good information for the developer.